# Application exited with status 2 when submitting Spark Job in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

When I submitted spark job using *cluster* deploy mode to the YARN cluster, the job will fail because of the `User application exited with status 2`.

But if the spark job is submitted using *client mode* it will work just fine.

Have anyone face the same problems? How can I fix this problems?

Thanks in advance!

** Add more figure

[image]
[image]

Comment: provide the whole stacktrace. and you code where you see this error.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting! I have added all error log that I take a snapshot. However, I can't copy the whole stack trace since it is logged in VDI and the the log now is deleted since operation team have to revert the server back to client mode.

Comment: you should be able to get the error stacktrace from yarn.  and I still don't see the code which cause this